# 2D js physics engine for HTML4

Tags: 2d, javascript, jbox2d

Is there any engine for Javascript like box2dweb that does not use Canvas? I need to build a game that works in HTML4 browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with Box2D web - perhaps just the way you are trying to draw the data. Are you using the debugRenderer?

[**Box2D - A web port**](http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/)

Physics simulations are always decoupled from the rendering routines (or they should be!). This is because they typically work within their own spatial regions that calculations are done in. This is metric in the case of **Box2D** but I wouldn't doubt if some other physics engine out there uses something else.

Rendering stuff out from physics data is another story - but to answer your question: **all the good ones!** However, what might NOT work (and won't in the case of Box2D) is their debug renderer. You'll need to implement your routine to render objects with physics bodies - re-implementing the HTML5 Canvas debug drawerer many physics engines ship wiith (including Box2D) if you want a debug view of the objects.